# Why is ie7 always in Quirks mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, doctype

Here is the DOCTYPE and XML declaration that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

But still IE7 is always going to quirks mode...

Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have anything before the DOCTYPE *apart from the XML prolog*, then you will trigger quirks mode in IE7. This includes white space and comments.

[The XML prolog will only trigger quirks mode in IE6.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/09/15/467901.aspx)

Comment: Grrr..thank you thank you!  This is my first Java environment and we were declaring the java libraries before the doctype...works as expected now.  Thanks again! StackOverflow rules!