# IE7 ignores CSS attribute selector only on pages coming from production server

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

On my website, IE7 seems to be ignoring certain CSS attribute selectors. The strange thing is that it only happens when the page comes from the production server. If I have the *exact same code* on my personal server, or saved on my hard drive, it works fine. Here is an example which causes the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
<title>IE display test</title>
<style type="text/css">
[type=button] {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Button 1"/>
<input type="button" value="Button 2"/>
<input type="button" value="Button 3"/>
</body></html>
```

Since the display on the buttons is set to "block", they should be arranged vertically. But *only when the page is served from my production server*, they are arranged horizontally. When I use the developer toolbar to inspect the style, I don't see the "display" property like I usually do. The only thing I can think of that would possibly cause this is the URL of the page or the response headers coming from the server. I can maybe figure it out by experimenting but that would be inconvenient and time-consuming so before I do that, I would like to ask: **Why is this happening and what can be done about it?**

**EDIT:** I came up with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wmq4M/). It looks fine on that site.

**EDIT 2:** Here are the response headers coming from the production server:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>   Content-Language: en-US
>   Content-Length: 291
>   Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2012 21:32:48 GMT

**EDIT 3:** Here are the response headers from my personal server:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2012 21:37:30 GMT
>   Server: Apache
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Encoding: gzip
>   Content-Length: 176
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

The production server is not applying gzip compression because it only does that for files above a certain size. If I add some stuff to make the file big enough, it uses gzip and I still see the problem in IE7, so this does not seem to have anything to do with gzip.

I tried configuring my personal server to send a "Content-Language" header like the production server and that did not trigger the problem.

I don't know if any of the other headers have anything to do with this. I can try testing them but it will be kind of tricky so it may take some time.

**EDIT 4:** I don't notice this problem in IE8, even if I turn on compatibility mode. I am testing this on Windows XP, in case that matters.

**EDIT 5:** I put the charset in the Content-Type header from my personal server. It didn't trigger the problem.

**EDIT 6:** Here are some screenshots:
Served from the production server:
[image: IE7 test on production server]

Served from my personal server:
[image: IE7 test on personal server]

Loaded directly from my hard drive:
[image: IE7 test directly from my hard drive]

**EDIT 7:** I finally got a clue as to what is causing this! I tried entering `javascript:alert(document.compatMode)` into the address bar. The personal and direct pages showed `CSS1Compat` but the production page showed `BackCompat`. **It seems like the browser is in quirks mode only when it is rendering the page from the production server.** So far, I have no idea why this is happening or what to do about it.

**EDIT 8:** I left out a detail: The screenshot is actually from my dev environment, which is emulating the production server but running on my own computer. That would make BoltClock's reply seem plausible, except for the fact that the same problem is showing up on our actual production server, which is on an IP address matching 173.*.*.*. Why do I see the problem on that server? Is that also a private IP address? It may be helpful to know that the actual production server is using https.

**EDIT 9:** Since the bounty expired, the problem stopped showing up on the production server but it still shows up in my dev environment (10.1.10.34). I have no idea why. I think I will blame it on cosmic rays unless I can come up with some more evidence.

Comment: Clear your cache. Check with the developer tools.

Comment: I tried clearing my cache. That didn't fix the problem. I doubt it is a caching problem because when I make changes, I see them.

Comment: What should I look for in the developer tools? I tried inspecting the style, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: you've got the right doctype.  Have you checked the response headers for `X-UA-Compatible`? that could be overriding the doctype..or check if the domain is in your trusted sites in IE it could be overriding doctype

Comment: input[type=button] seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Wmq4M/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185549/css-attribute-selector-for-input-type-button-not-working-on-ie7

Comment: @mdmullinax: IE7 doesn't recognize that header, it was only introduced with IE8.

Comment: AFAIK, there are no `X-UA-Compatible` response headers coming from the server, although I currently don't have a way to look at the headers in IE7.

Comment: I know that input[type=button] works fine but I am still curious as to what is causing that problem. My actual page is more complicated than that so I would like to use the selector without an element name. Also, knowing what causes the problem will give me some idea as to how to fix it, or possibly tell me what selectors will and won't work without having to experiment so much.

Comment: SKS, this question is similar to that other one but I am not sure if it is a duplicate. That question doesn't mention that the same selector behaves differently when it is served from a different server.

Comment: see if adding quotes around button `[type="button"]` has any effect

Comment: See Compatibility Section - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector

Comment: @mdmullinax, the quotes didn't help. Even if they did, they wouldn't answer my question as to why the same code behaves differently when served by a different server.

Comment: @Jawad, the page you linked to on Sitepoint did not have anything useful. I know there are some bugs with attribute selectors in IE7 but they are not relevant to this problem.

Comment: Try opening the page from Windows Explorer and see what happens, just for kicks.

Comment: Why don't you give those buttons a class name, and style them with the class selector in css?

Comment: I opened the page from Windows Explorer. It opened up in IE7 and it looks fine.

Comment: @SanderDeclerck, I know I can do that, but that would make my code significantly messier, and I am trying to figure out why the same code produces different results when served from a different server. Suppose this mysterious bug causes problems with class names only in certain situations. There would be a chance that if anyone else edits the page, they may trigger the bug. Understanding it would give me more information as to how to fix it or avoid it.

Comment: @mdmullinax, I forgot to mention that I clicked on the "Tools" menu, then "Internet Options", then the "Security" tab, then on "Trusted sites". I clicked on the "Sites" button and the list that came up was completely empty. I am guessing that this means that neither my personal server nor the production server is in my trusted sites. Please let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: Do you have [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)? Can you attempt to reproduce this behavior in IETester's IE7 mode?

Comment: See what security zone is being used. Also, open developer tools for each page and see what it says for "Document mode".

Comment: @BoltClock, I don't have IETester but I am thinking about getting it.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller, I don't think I am in any security zone. See my comment above. I don't see anything about document modes. I thought those were introduced in IE8 but I don't remember for sure.

Comment: @mikez302: I think "document mode" here refers to standards mode vs quirks mode. IE is known to comment out doctype declarations on a whim (it's bitten me before), causing a document to fall back to quirks mode. Not sure if IE7 is affected (check that with your developer tools), but IE8, IE9 *and* IE10 are...

Comment: @BoltClock, I thought you were referring to IE7 compatibility mode or something. Sorry about that. I am about to check if IE7 is going into quirks mode.

Comment: Well, @Devon_C_Miller and I nailed it, didn't we. I've seen this issue on SO many times over, but I can't figure out why it happens at all either.

Comment: @BoltClock: Maybe IE7 has something similar to what [IE8 has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966952/ie-css-problem-when-the-site-is-located-at-networkdrive/4967594#4967594)? `10.*` is a private IP address, maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @thirtydot: *Now* I see why there were earlier comments asking about trusted sites and so on...

Comment: not sure but i see that the server output of  http://eliasz.net/ie7DisplayTest.php is compressed .may be you can try disabling it or some .htaccess tweaks

Comment: I did some tests and I get the same result regardless of whether I enable or disable gzip compression.

Comment: I am getting different behavior than your screenshot suggests: http://i.imgur.com/Vozow.jpg

Comment: And my page reports that it is in standards mode.

Comment: Is your production server a virtual machine, or are any of the applications loaded as virtual apps?

Comment: Is your production machine within a domain?

Comment: Check if developer tool bar is installed for ie 7, you can do this by click View - > Toolbars - > Develop Tool bar. If you see developer tool bar it's installed and in this you may have incorrect document mode set.

Comment: Try resetting ie7 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/06/12/628499.aspx

Comment: @Anicho, I have the developer toolbar. I don't see anything about the document mode and I don't think the developer toolbar in IE7 has any obvious indication of the document mode. As stated in edit 7 in my question, the browser is going into quirks mode only for my production server. I am trying to figure out why and what to do about it.

Comment: @Anicho, I tried resetting my browser and it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Mike - Does the same thing happen when you use an external style sheet instead of inline CSS?

Comment: @webnoob: Pedantry: that's called an *internal style sheet*, not inline CSS.

Answer (score 8):

As discussed in the comments, according to [this answer by thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967594/106224) and [this answer by scunliffe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168131/106224), it seems very likely to be the effect of a security feature in Internet Explorer. Your production server lives within your intranet, and is being accessed via a private, class A IPv4 address (`10.*.*.*`), which I suspect basically causes IE7 to render pages in quirks mode ([and IE8 and newer to render pages in Compatibility View](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/12/03/compatibility-view-improvements-to-come-in-ie8.aspx)).

All this is just a guess, though, I'm afraid — I haven't been able to reproduce your problem in any IE browser on any system, at least not on your personal server or with my own files. If your production server is open to public access, not just technically, perhaps you could provide a link to it so we can debug further, as the problem is obviously localized to *just your production server*.

Comment: OK so apparently that's more an IE8 issue than an IE7 issue... let me do some more research on this.

Comment: Mysteriously, I can no longer reproduce the behavior. Perhaps I should have taken a screenshot... meanwhile, firing up Windows XP Mode.

Comment: Your explanation sounds kind of plausible, but see edit 8 above.

Comment: @mikez302: Oh, now that's strange... no, `173.*.*.*` addresses are not private IP addresses. Curious, how exactly does your development server emulate your production server?

Comment: We have the same bunch of Groovy and Grails code running on my work computer that we do on the production server, and I access it from my browser through either localhost or my own IP address. I don't know the details.

Comment: Is your production server publicly accessible?

Comment: I don't think it is accessible to the public. I will have to ask when I go to work tomorrow but the answer is probably no.

Comment: The production server is not publicly accessible. Sorry about that. I can maybe try to beg the people at my work some more to let me put up a test page on it but it seems doubtful.

Comment: What BoltClock says is true, I have managed to replicate a similar envrionment with an intranet site on IE7 causes the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just played around with the code on your personal server (eliasz.net), a file served through the file:// protocol, and served on a local server.

Your personal server and when rendered through the file:// protocol are both rendering correctly as they are rendered in 'edge' mode (the latest, rather than compatibility mode). However, on your production server and on your development server, they are rendering in compatibility mode. As BoltClock said, intranets do this by default. Obviously, this would apply for your development server (on a local IP like 10.1.10.34).

I think the production server is also on your local network, although it has a public static IP. In other words, when you are on the local network, the production server is served through the local network, not the internet. Hence, IE7 still sees it as an intranet site. Use `nslookup` to check how IE7 is resolving the domain name.

To get round the issue, you can add this to your header:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

and then turn off the setting in your IE that causes it to render intranet sites in compatibility mode.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, IE7 doesn't understand the `X-UA-Compatible` header.

Comment: Sorry, should have gone into further detail at the end. There is no such thing as 'compatibility mode' in IE7 - it was introduced in IE8. There is only 'quirks mode', and it is that which is being used.

Comment: What setting would cause IE to render intranet sites in quirks mode? Why would that make a difference? The screenshot above is in my dev environment. The actual production server (on a 173.*.*.* IP address) has the same problem but I was not able to put this simple test case up on it. I will try your X-UA-Compatible idea when I get a chance but I thought that didn't work in IE7.

Comment: @mikez302 Can you check the IP on which it is being served to you? Your IT department may have configured the DNS to serve it over the LAN so to IE, it's still a local site.

Comment: @mikez302 The setting is the intranet zone. The other possibility is that your web server (e.g. Apache or IIS) is inserting something. Have you checked the actual rendered source?

Comment: @mikez302 Have you checked the actual rendered source from the production server? It's possible that the web server software is inserting something.

Comment: I pinged the server and it looks like it is coming from a 50.*.*.* address. I could swear that it began with 173 last Friday, but either way, I don't think it would be considered private.

Comment: I don't think my server is inserting anything, except the headers as shown in the question. I tried running `curl "http://10.1.10.34:8080/appcentral/" | md5` and `curl "http://eliasz.net/ie7DisplayTest.php" | md5` from bash, and both times I got the same hash (3293b3a81b7fd185bfedac92bf3bb534).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6978/discussion-between-blowski-and-mikez302)

Answer (score 2):

> Be aware that certain conditions can force Internet Explorer to display pages in a document compatibility mode different from the one specified in the webpage. These include, but are not limited to, the following situations:
>
> - Compatibility View is enabled for the page.
> - The page is loaded in the Intranet zone and Internet Explorer is configured to use Compatibility View for pages loaded from the Intranet zone.
> - Internet Explorer is configured to display all websites in Compatibility View.
> - Internet Explorer is configured to use the Compatibility View List, which specifies a set of websites that are always displayed in Compatibility View.
> - The Developer Tools are used to override the settings specified in the webpage.
> - The webpage encountered a page layout error and Internet Explorer is configured to automatically recover from such errors by reopening the page in Compatibility View.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx

From this we can derive your running a site on your local intranet, ie 7 can't turn off this of the rendering as in ie8 you can stop local intranet sites being rendering in compat mode.

10.x.x.x ip address production server

file:// essentially local host

http:// through your local server

**UPDATE:**

Okay apologies IE has numerous problems running on the intranet, IE8+ is the issue above as you mentioned IE7 doesn't use compat mode it has quirks and standard. Knowing microsoft though they may have messed it up in one of the ie7 patch updates but I hate assumptions so if someone knows please let me know.

To resolve the issue I am afraid I can't give you a software level solution or a hardware change. If its always going to be an intranet site then I recommended upgrading network browsers to ie8 minimum.

I do have a html, css fix however(i know this is not what you want):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head> 
    <title>IE display test</title> 
    
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #buttons { 

        } 

        #button {
            display:block;
        }
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="buttons">
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Button 1"/> 
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Button 2"/> 
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Button 3"/> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't seem to like `[type="buttons"]` using `display:block;`.

Comment: OK, so what am I supposed to do about this? There is no compatibility mode in IE7 AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I see that one page is .html and the other is .php. It might be possible that your php page has some character (maybe hidden) before the doctype. It could make a difference on how IE accepts HTML and CSS.

Comment: Nice observation. It's not clear whether the production server is running a PHP script or serving a raw HTML file as is, though.

Comment: That distinction does not matter. Initially, I tested it from my personal server with a static HTML page. Then I converted it to PHP just for a quick and easy way to set some of the response headers. That did not affect the arrangement of the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this with both IE8 and IE9 and I found the solution!

Now this may not translate exactly to IE7, but it should point you in the right direction.

- Look through the menus for an item called "Compatibility View".
- Give it a click and it opens a dialog where you can add websites to be shown in "Compatibility View".
- Look below the list for a check box labeled "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"
- Uncheck it.

It appears that Microsoft considers a host part of the "intranet" when it is:

- joined to the same domain,
- identified by an unqualified host name (ex "server" vs "server.example.com"), or
- identified by a private IP address (10.x.x.x, 172.16-31.x.x, 192.168.x.x)

It also looks like nothing is considered "intranet" if the client system is not joined to a domain.

Answer (score 0):

I get a feeling it has something to do with the server (Based on the apache/coyote I guess you're using tomcat?) and either something to do with whitespaces, or BOF, or improper utf-8 setting (i've heard of issues where header claims to be utf-8 but isn't). If you have any whitespace before the html declaration, that might also trigger it to go into quirks mode. While I may be wrong, I get the feeling that your problem is similar to this one [Why is ie7 always in Quirks mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527297/why-is-ie7-always-in-quirks-mode)

Comment: Content-Length from the production server is exactly 291. Assuming CRLF line endings all the way, that makes it very unlikely, but I guess not completely impossible.

Comment: I am using LF line endings and UTF-8 encoding in all 3 cases.

Comment: @mikez302: LF line endings? Your production server seems to be serving CRLFs. That's the only way it could produce a response with a content length of 291.

Comment: @BoltClock, you were right. Somehow I accidentally saved the file on the server with CRLFs. But I just tested it with LF endings and I still see the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the answer is which server it came off but more a case of adding double quotes around the value in the CSS selector.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
<title>IE display test</title>
<style type="text/css">
[type="button"] {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Button 1"/>
<input type="button" value="Button 2"/>
<input type="button" value="Button 3"/>
</body></html>
```

Comment: IE7 hasn't been found to have problems with attribute selectors whether you exclude the quotes, or use single quotes, or use double quotes. Plus, as already mentioned, the same code works just fine in the personal and dev servers.