# IE7 changes order of css selectors

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

I have some css code that only hides a certain element if another element's value is 0

```
 #type_46[value="0"] ~ .exercise_dur {
    display: none;
  }
```

This works in every browser except ie7 (ie9 in ie7 mode/ie7 document mode)

When troubleshooting using ie dev tools, If I look directly at the styles list, I see:

```
[value='0']#type_46 ~ .exercise_dur
```

Which obviously breaks the selector and causes it not to work. If I manually (in the dev tools) correct this, it works perfectly without any issues.
Has anyone experienced this problem? If so, is there a workaround other than hiding the element in the javascript?

EDIT: (can't answer my own question yet so I have to edit)
It appears that the problem is  that ie7 is not dynamically updating the css. When the code is initialized, it doesn't work because the value is not set before the css loads. It updates if I force it to (i.e. change the code or disable/re-enable the style) but then doesn't update (even if I change the value) until it is forced again. ie7 is not a huge priority for this project and hiding the element is not absolutely necessary, so I think I'm going to leave this one for now and implement it in jquery if necessary later.

Thanks.

Comment: That does not break the selector; it's perfectly valid (even though it looks strange), and should work in IE7 as well as IE9's IE7 mode. Can we see your page?

Comment: Unfortunately it's part of a private project I'm not at liberty to share. Any idea why swapping the id and value selectors fixes it?

Comment: I do understand that IE7 trips up on attribute selectors sometimes, and this may be one of those times. Is there any way you can reproduce this behavior in a test case? Or if it's part of a private project, if your project is being hosted in an intranet then [this question seems similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915855/ie7-ignores-css-attribute-selector-only-on-pages-coming-from-production-server), although in that question IE7 completely ignores the selector outright.

Comment: Could you share the relevant HTML and relevant CSS then, just that we need for a test case? Have you tried with "!important"?

Comment: I'd like to but I can't get permission to post anything (sorry) however, when I disable then reenable the relevant css, it acts as it should. Is it possible it's reading the value attribute before it is set?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the bugs with sibling selectors that affect IE7.

Answer (score 1):

Support for the general sibling selector in IE7 is buggy at best. I recommend figuring out another way to select your elements, or use jQuery.

[Read more.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/buggy-css-selectors-cross-browser-jquery/)

Comment: This would be it, although the linked article doesn't describe what kind of bugs IE7 has.